# Как отправить ответ на post ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Я посылаю запрос на сервер вот так

```
    let url="some";
    let xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.send(btnNumber);
```

На сервере я его получаю и мне нужно отправить ответ клиенту. Как его отправить? Как его обработать(ответ на стороне клиента)? Могу ли я обработать новое html представление?

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<string> some()
        {
            try
            {
                using (StreamReader red = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    var text = await red.ReadToEndAsync();
                    db.Remove(new UpdatesModel() {Id = Convert.ToInt32(text)});
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            return "test";
        }
```

Comment: Отправить можете точно таким же образом, как ответ на гет запрос. На клиенте вы можете и всю страницу обновить ответом, и часть страницы и даже просто какие то данные, если ответ вернете в  формате json, например. Тут уже вам решать, что именно отправлять и как обрабатывать ответ.

Comment: Вы уже отправляете. Посмотрите на ответ xhr и поищите там ваш test

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите на ответ от запроса

```
let url="some";
let xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
}

xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.send(btnNumber);
```

думаю у вас должно там что-то быть :)

Comment: Да, я просто сразу после отправки запроса ответ смотрел, сервер не успевал обработать и выводил "". Теперь думаю как его применять

Comment: Сразу нельзя разве только xhr.open("POST", url, false); и только после этого (синхронный запрос/крайне нежелательный)

Comment: Добавьте xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
} там где я указал и смотрите в консоль

Answer (score 0):

Во первых метод контроллера должен возвращать IActionResult.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> some()
```

Тогда вы сможете вернуть любые данные с ответом 200:

```
return Ok(result);
```

Какие данные ждет клиент (json, xml, string) это уже другой вопрос.